# Typescript not allowing me to pass props to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two components. One is the App.tsx file and inside of it, I do an API call to get some data. I take that data and try to pass it down, but I get an error `Type 'Element' has no properties in common with type 'Props'.  TS2559` Props is the name of my interface that I have made for the App component. The other component is just the child component that wants to receive the props.

```js
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import UsersList from "./components/UsersList";
import Form from "./components/Form"

interface Props {
  userList?: any
}

const App = (): Props => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(usersList => {
        setUsers(usersList)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form />
      <UsersList userList={users}></UsersList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to add the parameter `const App = (props: Props)` or in this case `const App = ({usersList}: Props)`?

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the type after the () (`(): Props`), you're defining the return type. If you want to set the type of a parameter, you need to define it inside the () (`(props: Props)`).

Try this:

```js
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import UsersList from "./components/UsersList";
import Form from "./components/Form"

interface Props {
  userList?: any
}

const App = ({userList}: Props) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(usersList => {
        setUsers(usersList)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form />
      <UsersList userList={users}></UsersList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm still very new to TS, but thanks to people like yourself I am getting it more and more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have misplaced your `Props` type. As the example stands, you are saying that the `App` function should return `Props`.

You can either define it like this:

```
const App = (props: Props) => {
```

Or you can use the types provided by `React`:

```
const App: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
```